# INSTALLED_KERNEL_HEADERS missing while trying to compile ROM for android

Tags: android, custom-rom

Sorry but I m kind of new to this development world.

So basically when I tried to compile lineageos15.1 from source I recieved this error

```
ninja: error: 'INSTALLED_KERNEL_HEADERS', needed by '/home/oveno/los15.1/out/target/product/mido/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libcryptfs_hw_intermediates/cryptfs_hw.o', missing and no known rule to make it
```

Currently I have no idea how to fix it.
I have tried to reinstall the Ubuntu kernel headers but it didn't work.

It would be great if anyone could help me with a workaround.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you figure this one out?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. To fix it, I had to download the kernel of the device for which you want to build.
For example, in my case, for lineageos and a xperia M2 device (eagle), I had to get the kernel from https://github.com/f2065/android_kernel_sony_msm8226
and install it into `kernel/sony/msm8226` in the android build tree.